# Can I activate new FCM API (HTTP v1 API) in the Firebase console without any impact on sending messages via the legacy HTTP API?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We currently use old version of Firebase API Cloud Messaging (Legacy HTTP protocol) and we need to migrate to the new one (HTTP v1 API) before june 2024 due to the deprecation.

Just wondering if we can activate the new API version (in Firebase console > Cloud Messaging tab) without any impact on our application (sending messages is still based on the legacy API version).

[Firebase console > Cloud Messaging tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1C6J.png)

I didn't find any clear information about that on Firebase FAQ.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To migrate, you'll need to make changes in your server-side code that sends FCM messages. This will involve:

Updating endpoint URLs.
Using OAuth 2.0 for authentication instead of the legacy server key.
Adapting to the new payload structure if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Activating the versioned API makes no difference to the availability of the legacy API.

So you can safely have both APIs enabled while you migrate your code over from the legacy API to the versioned API, and then only turn off the legacy API once you have completed the migration.